# Profiling a VBScript ASP website?

Tags: performance, vbscript, asp-classic

I recently started working on an E-Commerce site that is written in VBscript/Classic ASP. Coming from a PHP background... this is... less than pleasant.

The largest issue I have right now is that there is a ton of extra an unnecessary code. I am looking for a way to get a stack trace... see what functions get called on a particular page... how long the calls take... things like that.

Another thing that has to be slowing things down is the obscene and unnecessary ammount of Dims at the top of all the documents. There has to be a bunch of those that are legacy and not being used. Getting rid of extra Dims should free up memory and make things faster... I hope.

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2010 on my workstation... but I have no idea how to import the site into that... or if I can even accomplish what I'm looking for with VS2010.

Any suggestions as to how I can profile ASP/VBscript is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to profile a classic ASP web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132120/how-to-profile-a-classic-asp-web-site)

Answer (score 2):

[How to profile a classic ASP web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132120/how-to-profile-a-classic-asp-web-site)

I suggest you learn what the Dim statements do BEFORE you declare them useless and the cause of your slowdowns: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/asp/article.php/3477891/ASP-Primer-Some-Basic-VBScript.htm